# Jmeter Heap Size increment

Tags: jmeter, heap-memory

When running Jmeter script using CLI instead of GUI, Is there a way to change the HEAP_SIZE for a single instance without changing that value in `"jmeter.bat"` or `"jmeter.sh"` files.

As example assume following command can be running with a given heap size. In that case how should that provide along with this command?

> `./jmeter -n -t /home/chamindu/Desktop/PerformanceTesting_colud/Jmeter/100tenants_with_refresh.jmx -l /home/chamindu/Desktop/PerformanceTesting_colud/Jmeter/100tenants_with_refresh_Results.jtl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [this line](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/jmeter#L40) of `jmeter` startup script:

```
##   HEAP             (Optional) Java runtime options for memory management
##                    used when JMeter is started.
##                    Defaults to "-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"
```

you should be able to manipulate the HEAP [environment variable](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-and-list-environment-variables-in-linux/) value like:

```
HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m" && ./jmeter -n -t /home/chamindu/Desktop/PerformanceTesting_colud/Jmeter/100tenants_with_refresh.jmx
```

or

```
export HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"
```

or add the next line to your [shell profile](https://www.tecmint.com/understanding-shell-initialization-files-and-user-profiles-linux/) so it would be applied on startup:

```
HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"
```

More information: [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

Answer (score 0):

```
HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m" && ./jmeter -n -t /home/chamindu/Desktop/PerformanceTesting_colud/Jmeter/100tenants_with_refresh.jmx
```

This is the exact answer to the above issue.Thanks